# VC++ on Visual Studio 2010: Release builds using debug heap

Tags: c++, visual-studio, performance, heap-memory

I'm benchmarking/optimizing a slow C++ application, and in taking some stackshots I found that the release build of my application is using the debug heap, as some of the stack traces found  would indicate:

```
ntdll.dll!string "Enabling heap debug options\n"()  + 0x11056 bytes
```

This is a 64-bit application running on Windows 7. I see two or three other complaints about this problem in the exact same environment online, but without any responses.

Does anyone have a clue why Windows or Visual Studio would be using the debug heap for a release build C++ project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The debug heap is used when a program is run under debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360900/visual-c-difference-between-start-with-without-debugging-in-release-mode/4375879#4375879) (profilers often manifest themselves as debuggers). In order to bypass it the program should be started without debugging, then the debugger should be attached to a running process.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I never knew that, though I'll admit I don't see the benefit in forcing a release application to use the debug heap - isn't the point of release to mimic as closely as possible real-world scenarios!?

Comment: @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi: This thing is actually not that well-known, I too was suprised to know it. Well, debug heap facilitates debugging and debugger facilitates debugging so I guess they decided to combine it. Also it's not done by Visual Studio or anything like that - it's done by Windows.