# Cannot open Database MyDB requested by the login.The login failed.Login failed for user "myUser"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

I have a SQL Server Express database connection problem.

I have WPF application which connects to my database using LINQ-to-SQL .

When I run the application in debug mode F5, the application works fine but when I run it CTRL+F5 I get connection to SQL error

> Cannot open Database MyDB requested by the login.The login failed.Login failed for user "myUser"

I have checked in Google and tried all the suggested solutions but nothing helped...:(

Can anyone help me?
thanks....

Comment: Are you giving your application the connection settings due to command line arguments set in the project properties?

Comment: @juergend you mean connection string?

Comment: yes the connection string or parts of the connection string. Check your project settings: Debug and Release setting can be configured differently.

Comment: @juergend I switched to release mode , and my settings are the same as in the debug mode (or there is something I don't understand...), and still if I run by F5 it works fine but Ctrl+F5 doesn't work...

Comment: @juergend it's interesting thing I've found out - when I wrote my connection string as string ("MyConnString") and didn't take it from app.config - it worked....

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the different variable initialization behavior of different run modes.

In the “Start with debugging” mode, the un-initialized variables are set to the default values. But in the “Start without debugging”, the variables are left random.

For example, you have:

```
int iHowMany;
```

In the “Start with debugging” mode, `iHowMany` is initialized to `0`. But in the “Start without debugging” mode, the value of `iHowMany` is random.

It is easy to find all the un-initialized variables. The VC compiler generates a warning for using an un-initialized variable. Just go through the compiler warning list, find them and initialize them.

[(Source)](http://www.kevingao.net/programming/the-difference-between-start-with-debugging%E2%80%9D-and-%E2%80%9Cstart-without-debugging.html)

You should also check that question:

[difference between debugging modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360900/visual-c-difference-between-start-with-without-debugging-in-release-mode)

Comment: I removed my app.config file , switched 'Active solution configuration' to 'Release' mode , added a new app.config file and my application started working.....